# Wordpress media upload define default meta values

Tags: wordpress, image

i want to add default values to metadata of images automatically while/after they are uploaded.

```
// add default values to custom fields upon upload

add_action( 'add_attachment', 'as_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function as_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {
// Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing
    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID )) {
        if (strlen(trim(get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'photographer', true))) == 0 ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'photographer', 'unknown' );
        }
        if (strlen(trim(get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'copyright', true))) == 0 ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'copyright', 'not defined' );
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine for the custom fields 'photographer' and 'copyright' but i also want to do it for the image caption. In another section of the code (hooked to attachment_fields_to_save) i am successfully using this statement to fill empty captions

```
    if (strlen(trim($post['post_excerpt'])) == 0) {
    $pretext = '[Attribution: ';
    $pretext .= get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'photographer', true);
    $pretext .= '; Copyright: ';
    $pretext .= get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'copyright', true);
    $pretext .= ']';
    $post['post_excerpt'] = $pretext.' '.$post['post_excerpt'];
    }
```

but i would rather move it to the 'add_attachment' hook. But when i do try to add it the image upload fails. I think because it uses the $post variable which is not used by the hook. i tried to replace $post with get_post($post_ID) to limit myself to the variables used by the hook but that didnt work either. I also tried to put

```
$post = get_post($post_ID)
```

before the if statement but then the whole site crashes, probably its some kind of global variable i shouldnt mess with by assigning it manually.

So my question is how can i fit the if statement in the 'add_attachment' hook, or, more general, how can i assign a default caption to images upon upload.

Comment: Refer to this answer here [Can I add custom meta for each image uploaded via media-upload.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/can-i-add-custom-meta-for-each-image-uploaded-via-media-upload-php)

Comment: appreciated! the solution there hooks to 'attachment_fields_to_save' which i am already using but that only fires when manually clicking the 'update' button on the attachment view, not automatically upon upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to automatically fill in a default caption upon upload

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'as_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload' );
function as_set_image_meta_upon_image_upload( $post_ID ) {
// Check if uploaded file is an image, else do nothing
    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID )) {
        //default photographer
        if (strlen(trim(get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'photographer', true))) == 0 ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'photographer', 'unknown' );
        }
        //default copyright
        if (strlen(trim(get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'copyright', true))) == 0 ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'copyright', 'not defined' );
        }
        //default caption
        $my_image_meta = array(
            'ID' => $post_ID,
            'post_excerpt' => '[Attribution: unknown; Copyright: not defined] ',
        );
        wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );   
    }
}
```

when i tried to load the actual values of 'photographer' and 'copyright' they returned empty, i suppose because there are just being filled in the same hook. good enough though